# int to string in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

How do you convert an int to a string in Link to EF?

The clr cant imagine casting an int to a string and Entity framework cant figure out what SQL snippet to translate `.ToString()` into.

So how do you write a linq statement that returns a string instead of an int?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: EF version 4. Does that make a difference?

Comment: EF >= 6.1 supports `ToString`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Sadly EF does not know how to convert `.ToString()`. You must use the embedded function SqlFunctions.StringConvert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466292.aspx
Also there is no overload for int so you must typecast to double :-(

```
var vendors = 
   from v in Vendors  
   select new
   {             
       Code = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.VendorId)
   };
```

Comment: B"H
Wow, that sucks.
What I do now is always project to an intermidiate (usualy anonymous) type in the select and then project into my real objects in the next step after a AsEnumerable() or something like that

Comment: i have to pass this converted value in where clause

Comment: It's also often important to call Trim() on the output to avoid having your string come out padded.

Comment: And how does one use this in EntityDataSource?