# x.ToString() is not supported by the entity framework!

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Entity framework doesn't recognize my ToString method that converts the route object to specifix string:

```
public IEnumerable<Route> GetRoutes(string prefix, string searchPattern, string code)
{
    return Routes.
        Where(x => code == null || x.Code == code).
        Where(x => searchPattern == null || x.ToString().Contains(searchPattern)).
        Where(x => prefix == null || x.ToString().StartsWith(prefix));
}
```

Here is my Route entity:

```
 public class Route : IDataEntity, ISoftDeletable
    {
        public virtual long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<LocationInRoute> Locations { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (LocationInRoute loc in Locations)
            {
                if (str.Length > 0)
                {
                    str.Append(" > ");
                }
                str.Append(loc.ToString());
            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
    }
```

All the `x.ToString()` throws an exception of not supported in linq to entities..
Any workaround?

Comment: Please define `Route` class and which property of it you need to compare to `searchPattern` or `prefix`

Comment: Might help to give more information on Route.

Comment: Remember that the C# code you type in an entity query is never executed! Instead, the expression tree is evaluated and turned into SQL statements. How could ToString() be converted into SQL?

Comment: My guess is that this is happening because LinqToEntities can't translate your `ToString` to SQL. What you can do, if it's possible, is to apply the filters that don't have the `ToString` first, then call to list to enumerate the results, then apply the other filters (locally on the list).

Comment: @Alex R., tofutim: I added definition of Route. @MattDavey: I understand the problem but I son't know how to workaround this. @AbdouMoumen: AsEnumerable might cause a lot of work on the .net and on the sql - the .net should perform filter an many objects and the sql has to return many objects.

Comment: *"my ToString method that converts the route object to specifix string"*. This conversion takes place client-side, you need a way to make that translation server-side in order to make queries against it..

Comment: IMO this question can be closed now as not-reproducible. The issue doesn't exist any more, except in old EF version of which I doubt they're still in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this on client side (`ToString`).

You must create SQL function which will do your evaluation - it can either do only string concatenation of you locations (I believe it is related entity) or you can do the whole test in custom function. Then you can import that function into your entity model (EDMX) and create `EdmFunctionAttribute` to call it - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456847.aspx).

Comment: I understand what you sais but my problem with the EdmFuncitons is that the code is not on its right place. It should be in Route class and not on the SQL server or on the xml that describe the edmx. There is something wrong with the approach of putting all "problematic" functions on the db or on the xml.

Comment: @Naor: I understand your concerns but unfortunately it is not possible. You must decide if you want your logic to be executed on the database or on the application server - you cannot have combined execution. Execution cannot pass its physical boundary => either use database approach I described or load all routes and use linq-to-objects with your approach.

Comment: @Naor: Even if you will be able to rewrite the query to pure linq-to-entities you can be sure that the logic will not be in your entity but in the query itself.

Comment: Isn't there any way to create a property on the edmx that wil calculate the ToString()'s result so that I will be able to use this property on linqto entities queries?

Comment: @Naor: Only if the property value will be calculated in the database and mapped in your entity model. Linq-to-entities cannot access non-mapped properties.

Answer (score 2):

> Entity framework doesn't recognize my ToString method that converts the route object to specifix string.

That's right.  Entity Framework can't convert the methods you write in c# into sql.

Entity Framework converts expressions to sql.  Sometimes those expressions represent calls to methods (such as `Queryable.Where`) and Entity Framework knows about those specific .net framework methods and how to translate them into sql.

How do you expect the database to new up a StringBuilder?

---

PS:  this or'ing of criteria in the query is a terrible way to go.  You shouldn't construct one query to rule them all.  Instead, conditionally construct the query:

```
IQueryable<Route> query = Routes

if (code != null)
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Code == code)
}
if (searchPattern != null)
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Locations.Any(loc => loc.Name.Contains(searchPattern)))
}
if (prefix != null)
{
  query = query.Where(x => x.Locations.First().Name.StartsWith(prefix));
}
```

Comment: I know the problem! I don't expect the db to deal with StringBuilder but I expect there will be something to solve such issues. Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 2):

`ToString()` is supported by newer versions of Entity Framework (from version 6.1 onwards)

See [Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx) of EF 6.1:

> **What’s in EF6.1**
>
> EF6.1 adds the following new features:
> [...]
>
> - Support for .ToString, String.Concat and enum HasFlags in LINQ Queries.

---

(Well, the question is already a few years old, but maybe this information might help others...
See also related question [How to use ToString SelectListItem with Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25410330/314334))

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which property of `Route` class you need to compare with `searchPattern` or `prefix`. You cannot implicitly do a `.ToString()` in your scenario.

Comment: But I need to compare tthe to string.. Do you suggest to add a property that stores the ToString to the entity??..

Comment: In route class I override ToString.

Comment: @Naor, can you make a getter instead of overriding `ToString`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to have a preperty called `ID` or `Name` which you want to compare with the `searchPattern` and then use:

```
 .Where(x => searchPattern == null || x.Name.Contains(searchPattern));
```

Because I'm asuuming that x demonstrate an entity, so, how do you want to compare the entiy's name itself with a search patternn ?

**Edit:**

After seeing the changes in the question, it's still unable to use `ToString()` method in this query because it's not able to convert to a SQL Statement.

Now, you have two options:

The first one: (I'm not sure if applicable depend on the suspected data size), try to load all the records from the database using `ToList()` extension before calling `Where` extension.
This should work well but it might cause a problem with huge tables.

The second one: You have to create a stored procedure and move the logic to the database.

Comment: The compare to searchPattern should be againt the ToString() result.

Comment: Instead ToList I can use AsEnumerablt but as you wrote this might load many many objects to the .Net. The scont option is not better because I just converted my application to use the EF4 and I want to leave all the stored procedures stuff - logic on stored procedure is bad design.

Comment: @ Naor: I think you can not move everything to EF, there will be still some limitations that you can not deal with in EF. I think in this situation, moving logic to DB might be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540953/746754) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089135/746754) might provide some help. Note that the suggested approach in the second link will not work for LINQ to Entities because it uses ToString. To make it work replace the CreateLike method with:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateLike<T>( PropertyInfo prop, string value )
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ) );
    Expression instanceExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( parameter, prop );            
    if( prop.PropertyType != typeof( System.String ) )
    {
        var cast = Expression.Convert( instanceExpression, typeof( double? ) );
        MethodInfo toString = typeof( SqlFunctions ).GetMethods().First( m => m.Name == "StringConvert" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 && m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof( double? ) );
        instanceExpression = Expression.Call( toString, cast );                
    }
    var like = Expression.Call( instanceExpression, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant( value, typeof( string ) ) );
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>( like, parameter );
}
```

Comment: I don't know if either are solutions, just workarounds. But they helped me when I hit exactly the same problem 2 years after your post. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky solution you can concat like this: key its an string property and key its an int?, its not the best performance solution but it works

```
    .Select(x => new Balance {
 Amount = x.Gem_Amount ?? 0,
 Balance = balance,
 Key = "" +(int)x.Key
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: The (old) issue here is that `ToString` was not supported. In EF versions where that's true this concatenation isn't supported either. So it's not a work-around and not an answer to the question.

Comment: Had you tryed ? it workfs

Comment: Look carefully what I'm saying. It works *now*, and `ToString` also works now. But where `ToString` didn't work, this "workaround" didn't work either. Therefore: not an answer.