# LINQ string[] against multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a table dataContext.Customer with the following fields

```
    FName    varchar
    LName    varchar
    Phone    varchar
    DOB      datetime
    Address  varchar
```

The table is filled with some sample data, lets say:

```
    John | Smith | 3051112222 | 01/01/1978 | Roosevelt Av 787
    Aron | Frank | 7871112222 | 01/01/1979 | Lambda Street 305
    Dick | Bush  | 9512221111 | 01/01/1980 | John Street 1
    John | Allen | 7872222222 | 01/01/1981 | Liberty Av 555
```

We also have a string array with an arbitrary number of elements, for example:

```
    search[0] = "1978"
    search[1] = "John"
```

I need a LINQ query that will compare each field of the table against each item in the string array incrementally using "contains" or "any" (meaning LIKE in SQL) and only return the rows that match all the given conditions in a record, based on the previous search[] example the LINQ query should return only record #1.

Another example can be:

```
    search[0] = "Bush"
    search[1] = "111"
    search[2] = "John"
```

and only record #3 should by returned. Finally for:

```
    search[0] = "John"
```

Records #1, #3 and #4 should be returned (I think the idea is clear)

There's a question on how to compare a string[] against field in:
[LINQ: Entity string field contains any of an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757214/linq-entity-string-field-contains-any-of-an-array-of-strings)

If the answer is a 50 lines C# routine I prefer to solve this directly in the database via stored procedure.

It will be awesome if there is some kind of "reflection" trick to iterate all the field on dataContext.Customers while doing the query (obviously the real table don't have 5 fields).

Performance is not a problem.

I'm pretty sure this cannot be done in a single LINQ line because of the logic needed for the multiple match, but it never hurt to ask, much less to learn anything new :)

UPDATE:
Ok, here's a simple SQL code that will accomplish the task. Note that I have cut the amount of search variables to just 2 for clarity. In the real life scenario we can limit the amount of arguments to 10 search parameters. I deliberately did not use functions (well, except for CONVERT) to keep the SQL as simple as possible to see if there is any way to accomplish this in LINQ. Here's the SQL:

```
    declare @_SEARCH1 varchar(1000)
    select  @_SEARCH1 = 'John'
    declare @_SEARCH2 varchar(1000)
    select  @_SEARCH2 = '111'

    select  *
    from    CUSTOMER
    where
            FName + ' ' + LName + ' ' + Phone + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, DOB, 101) + ' ' + Address like '%'+@_SEARCH1+'%'
    and     FName + ' ' + LName + ' ' + Phone + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, DOB, 101) + ' ' + Address like '%'+@_SEARCH2+'%'
```

So the question is, is there a way to write a LINQ that will generate this simple SQL? (please note that the comparison is done in the database via 'LIKE', not in the application)

UPDATE 2: Although solutions like the one from Francisco will generate the "LIKE" statement it will fail doing the comparison. The other solutions that pulls all the data from the table to the webserver will do the match correctly, but is totally impractical.

Accepted answer to RUNE FS since is the cleanest solution and will work will any number of fields.

Comment: Will this be something that will need to perform reasonably well?  You might want to look at something like using [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) and just building an index that concats all of your columns together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that '\t' would never be part of the data you could do the following. You can of course substitute with any other character. With that assumption you could do as below:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
                                      string[] criteria){

var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                          .Where(p=>p.GetGetMethod() != null);
return from s in sequence
       let text = properties.Aggregate("",(acc,prop) => 
                                               acc + 
                                               "\t" + 
                                               prop.GetValue(s,null)
                                       )
       where criteria.All(c => text.Contains(c))
       select s;

}
```

**EDIT**
I originally didn't include the usage since I found no collection in the original post but assuming the sequence is defined as `IEnumerabl<Person>` and can be accessed as a property called Persons on a variable db. the code would look similar to:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = db.Persons.Where(criteria);
```

Comment: wont compile in VS2010, also, how do I apply this IEnumerable to execute the LINQ in the given example?

Comment: It says "A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: sorry I hand edited after pasting from VS2010. it compiles now

Comment: When executed throws an error in this line
acc + "\t" + prop.GetValue(prop, null)
saying "Object does not match target type"

Answer (score 5):

Using the PredicateBuilder

```
void Main()
{
    var search = new string[] { "Romania","RO"};
    var query = from c in countries.AllAny(search)
        orderby c.name
        select c;
    query.Dump();
}

public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> AllAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string[] search)    
    {           
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute),true).Any()).Select(n=>n.Name);        
        var andPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        foreach ( var term in search )
        {
            var orPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
            foreach (var property in properties )
                orPredicate = orPredicate.Or(CreateLike<T>(property,term));
            andPredicate = andPredicate.And(orPredicate);
        }
        return query.Where(andPredicate);
    }
    private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> CreateLike<T>( PropertyInfo prop, string value)
    {       
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "f");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, prop);            
        var toString = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, "ToString", null, null);
        var like = Expression.Call(toString, "Contains", null, Expression.Constant(value,typeof(string)));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(like, parameter);       
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> CreateLike<T>( string propertyName, string value)
    {
        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);     
        return CreateLike<T>(prop, value);
    }

}

// http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T> ()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T> () { return f => false; }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.OrElse (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }

  public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T> (this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
  {
    var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke (expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression> ());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
          (Expression.AndAlso (expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
  }
}
```

**Update**
This code is a generic solution for the following query

```
from c in countries
where (c.name.ToString().Contains(search[0]) || c.name.ToString().Contains(search[1]))
    && (c.iso_code.ToString().Contains(search[0]) || c.iso_code.ToString().Contains(search[1]))
    /*&& ...*/
orderby c.name
select c
```

This code can be improved in many ways. For sample, for the string properties, there is no need to call ToString before Contains ( this will generate a convert(nvarchar)) and I really think someone who needs this will only want to look at the varchar, nvarchar columns.

Comment: Im getting errors in these 2 lines
        orPredicate = orPredicate.Or(CreateLike<T>(property, term));
    andPredicate = andPredicate.And(orPredicate);
Says that "No overload for method OR takes 1 argument"... same for the second line but with AND.

Comment: maybe you're having a copy paste issue, this code is tested with LinqPad ( double tested now)

Comment: Im using VS2010, I have all the "using" in place, even added Reflection

Comment: using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

Comment: did you have any success with this?

Comment: Nop, I already had linq and linq.expressions in the usings.
Anyway this kind of solution will send all the table data to the webserver.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Welcome. It doesn't get the whole table into the web servers memory. It generates LIKE clauses. Too bad you can't compile this or test it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think linq to sql can do this efficiently, but linq to objects might be able to help if you can stomach moving the entire table over the wire between your application code and the database exactly one time per search.

The first step is to get a DataReader that will read through *all* of the records in your table. It's important to use a datareader, because you probably don't want to fill up memory with an entire table (and then again, maybe you do -- see my note about caching near the end).

Once you have that, you need to convert it to an IEnumerable for use with linq-to-objects.  You can do that with a simple two-line utility method, like so:

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> EnumerableFromDataReader(IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
        yield return reader;
}
```

The actual code I normally use is a little more complicated, but what I do might not fit in well with how the rest of your project is structured so I'll leave it at this short method for now.

Once we have the Enumerable, we take advantage of the *composable* nature of linq to get some (relatively) simple (or at least brief) code like this:

```
IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SearchMyTable(string[] filters)
{
    var results = EnumerableFromDataReader(GetMyTable());

    foreach (string filter in filters)
    {
       results = results.Where(r => String.Join("",r.GetValues().Cast<string>().ToArray()).Contains(filter));
    }

    return results;
}
```

It's not a single linq query, but it's not exactly 50 lines of code either.

Ignoring network latency, the performance of this code is actually quite good. If you want to play with some caching for all or part of the table after the columns are joined, the performance is amazing.

**Update:**  There is (at least) one flaw in this code. For each filter, I re-convert all the rows that survive to that filter to a string... even if I've already done so for a previous filter. The way to fix this is to first do a projection to pair the rows with the string version. But as it's after 11pm my time, I'll leave the code as it stands for now. The good news is the the final fixed code should be the same length: just add a `.Select()` call to the first and last lines and change up the middle of the foreach loop a bit.

Comment: That's pretty clever!
However as you pointed out, moving the entire table to the web server is impractical. As I said, performance is not an issue, as long as the load stays in the database.
I'll wait till tomorrow and then I will solve this with a SP.

Comment: About LINQ to objects (or ADO Entities or LINQ to entities or w/e is called) I can't do that since the entire project is using LINQ to SQL. But anyway, thanks for sharing your approach.

Comment: @user - IQueryable (the basis for linq to sql) implements IEnumerable, and therefore the results of a linq to sql query that returns the entire table (should be easy to write) could be easily used with the linq to objects extension methods.

Comment: LINQ to objects and LINQ to SQL are not mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# compiler at hand right now but I have this idea:

Declare a lambda Expression like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> GetFilterFromString(string input)
{
    return p=> p.FName.Contains(input) ||
               p.LName.Contains(input) ||
               p.Phone.Contains(input) ||
               p.DOB.ToString().Contains(input) ||
               p.Address.Contains(input) ||    
}
```

Implementation may vary depending on your needs (like concatenating all fields, like you did with your SQL query).

Then in your main query function:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = dataContext.Customers;
foreach(string inputSearch in search)
{
    customers = customers.Where(GetFilterFromString(inputSearch));
}
IEnumerable<Customer> results = customers.AsEnumerable();
```

I think the main advantage of this approach is that you have to declare GetFilterFromString once. Hope it is what you're looking for.

**Edit:**

Ok, so I read the SQL statement you were looking for (kind of late... but anyway).
I think it's easy to adapt my solution. We will have to tweak the lambda expression a little:

```
public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> GetFilterFromString(string input)
    {
        return p => (p.FName + " " +
                   p.LName + " " +                  
                   p.Phone + " " +
                   p.DOB.ToString() + " " +
                   p.Address)
                   .Contains(input) 
    }
```

Comment: Will this method pull all the records from the database to the webserver? Or will this approach generate a "LIKE" sql statement?

Comment: This will pull only the records you need. I forgot to write that =)

Comment: The generated SQL from your code generates this:
WHERE ([t0].[Description] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[AddressL1] LIKE @p1) OR ([t0].[RQ] LIKE @p2)
The problem is the "ORs"... if a record match ANY of the search criteria it will be returned.
That was close man! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be what i might do is, first ill get the records from DB having first name compared with the array item i have.

Once i get the the subset of the table data (assuming that the structure of DB table is same and the array structure as well meaning that array[0] is always first name), then i search for what ever pattern i am looking for in the memory.

I am sure this is not the exactly solution your hoping for. But lemme think further, mean while i am open for more ideas folks :)

Comment: You are right, the order of the search[] is arbritrary. I will edit the question to show that.

Comment: Or what else you can do is, take the whole table row and convert it into a string format, then you can do a regex or contains search on it from the search[] items. But again converting it to a string is costly.

Comment: If performance were an issue I wont be using LINQ :)
This query will run against a 56k records table, so no problem there.
Again, If the solution is to complex I'll solve this with a cursor in a stored procedure, but I will like to give LINQ a try.

Comment: As yourself have suggested, you may have to write multiple queries. For sure there isnt a straight way to do it. Plus your saying the search[] contents are random. So linq is quite hectic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Francisco's answer but with a single application of the where clause:

```
string[] search = new string[] { "Bush", "111", "John" };
var customers = new[]   { 
                            new {FName = "Dick", Surname = "Bush", Phone = "9512221111", DOB = new DateTime(1980,01,01), Address = "John Street 1" },
                            new {FName = "John", Surname = "Smith", Phone = "3051112222",  DOB =  new DateTime(1978,01,01), Address = "Roosevelt Av 787"}
                        };


var result = customers.Where(customer => search.All(term =>
                    customer.FName.Contains(term)
                    || customer.Surname.Contains(term)
                    || customer.DOB.ToString().Contains(term)
                    || customer.Phone.Contains(term)
                    || customer.Address.Contains(term)
                    ));
```

Comment: It throws an error while executing:
"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator"
I'm using VS2010