# Get IQueryable<T> where any field of T contains a given string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 have a large 20 property entity made up of strings, dates, nullable dates and ints. Is it possible to use Linq to do a contains against every field.

I don't want to have to construct a linq statement with every field

```
results = list.Where(house => house.Date1.ToString().Contains(search)||
                              house.Address1.Contains(search)||
                              house.Address2.Contains(search)||
                              house.Address3.Contains(search)||
                              .........................)
```

I guess I want to convert all properties to string (where necessary) and then do a contain on each of them? Ideally this would occur at the DB level.

I guess I can't concatenate them as it may cause false matches if end and start of two fields created the searched text? Any ideas?

### Update

I'm currently the second answer from this [LINQ string[] against multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087496/linq-string-against-multiple-fields) using LinqKit AsExpandable and EF conversion functions to string based on type. However I don't seem to be able to find a SqlFunction that converts DateTime to string

Comment: Using the same search string on every field looks like really bad code smell to me.

Comment: I'd agree. However client wants to search all fields in data from single text box. It is a proof of concept at moment though

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's essentially a full text search.  As a business requirement that makes sense.  Not sure if EF is the best tool for the job though.

Comment: @Servy That's what I meant by it, I just did not know how to say it.

Comment: it seems like you should make a new table that stores Id + Body where body is a concatenation of the fields you need to search, then slap a full text index on Body

Comment: Yeah probably could just do it against the ViewModel. It doesn't have to be at the DB level. Just if it was possible it would be good as there is a lot of data

Comment: Regardless of other aspects it is possible. My idea is to use Dynamic Linq and make the Sql-like where expression string. Remember to check for nulls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the general idea here is to use `PredicateBuilder` to OR together a bunch of expressions each representing a `Contains` check on a given property.  You can use reflection to find all of the properties of the given type to create an expression for.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SearchAllFields<T>(string searchText)
{
    var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = Expression.Constant(false);

    var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"
        , new[] { typeof(string) });
    var toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");

    var stringProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(string));

    foreach (var property in stringProperties)
    {
        var stringValue = Expression.Call(Expression.Property(t, property.Name),
            toStringMethod);
        var nextExpression = Expression.Call(stringValue,
            containsMethod,
            Expression.Constant(searchText));

        body = Expression.OrElse(body, nextExpression);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, t);
}
```

Comment: Ok so this won't work against the DB as it uses ToString etc? I haven't been able to get it to work against the DB as I can't convert DateTime to string at EF level. I guess I will make an IQUeryable extension out of this or similar and just have to do it on server

Comment: @GraemeMiller you could change this and use SqlFunctions.StringConvert instead for numeric fields (casted to double or decimal if they are not). So the code could work with fields of type string (no need to use StringConvert), "numeric" fields (with SqlFunctions.StringConvert), but not boolean or complex types for example (don't think it would make sense anyway)...

Answer (score 1):

I have recently created an nuget package that solves this very issue using extension methods

### https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/

This will allow the following code...

```
using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions;
//...
var result = list.Search(h => search, h.Date1.ToString(),
                                      h.Address1,
                                      h.Address2,
                                      h.Address3,
                                      ...etc...)
```

Check out the github page if you want to use the code:
https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions

When connected to a sql database, you get something close similar tothe following sql:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Date1] AS [Date1], 
       [Extent1].[Address1] AS [Address1], 
       [Extent1].[Address2] AS [Address2], 
       [Extent1].[Address3] AS [Address3] 
FROM   [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Address1] LIKE N'%searchTerm%') 
   OR ([Extent1].[Address2] LIKE N'%searchTerm%') 
   OR ([Extent1].[Address3] LIKE N'%searchTerm%')
```

Hope this helps