# How to use ToString SelectListItem with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have some code like below. I got run time exception says:

> "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."

The exception cause by `"Value = sup.SupplierID.ToString()"` and `"Value = cat.CategoryID.ToString()"` It seems entity framework can not generate expression tree with `ToString()` but for `SelectListItem` I have to give it a string.

Who can provide simple fix solution will be great appreciate.

---

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductEditViewModel : Product
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierDropDownItems { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorieDropDownitems { get; set; }
    }
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProductEdit(Int32 ProductId)
{
    var northwind = new NorthwindEntities();

    var q = from p in northwind.Products
            where p.ProductID == ProductId
            select new ProductEditViewModel
            {
                ProductID = p.ProductID,
                ProductName = p.ProductName,
                UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                SupplierDropDownItems = from sup in northwind.Suppliers select new SelectListItem { Text = sup.CompanyName, Value = sup.SupplierID.ToString(), Selected = p.Supplier.SupplierID == p.SupplierID },
                CategorieDropDownitems = from cat in northwind.Categories select new SelectListItem { Text = cat.CategoryName, Value = cat.CategoryID.ToString(), Selected = p.Category.CategoryID == p.CategoryID },
                Discontinued = p.Discontinued
            };

    return View(q.SingleOrDefault());
}


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierID, "SupplierID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("SupplierID", Model.SupplierDropDownItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cat.CategoryID)
```

The other option is to enumerate all records in memory and then use `ToString` like:

```
from sup in northwind.Suppliers.AsEnumerable()
select new SelectListItem { Text = sup.CompanyName, Value = sup.SupplierID.ToString(), Selected = p.Supplier.SupplierID == p.SupplierID },
```

`AsEnumerable` would fetch all the records from the database and load them up in memory, so your call `ToString` would not be required to translate to SQL.

Comment: The run time exception gone, but when select an item from the dropdown list, it shows an validation error message "The field SupplierID must be a number."

Comment: @Matthew, Probably your Model has `SupplierID` specified as `int` and since you are passing a string, you are getting an error. I am not sure if I can help you in that. I have little idea of MVC

Comment: After remove validation "@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>" everything works fine. For dropdown list selection, do not need a validation. :-) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using an old version of EF - `ToString()` is supported by newer versions of Entity Framework (from version 6.1 onwards)

See [Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx) of EF 6.1:

> **What’s in EF6.1**
>
> EF6.1 adds the following new features:
> [...]
>
> - Support for .ToString, String.Concat and enum HasFlags in LINQ Queries.

Comment: Yes. I am using Entity Framework 5.0 because currently Oracle ODAC 12.1.0.1.2 do not support EF 6.1. Hopeful Oracle release new ODAC to support EF6.1.