# Reusable functions/expressions in LINQ to Entities select clauses

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a lot of code that casts entities to data transfer objects similar to this:

```
var result = from t in DatabaseContext.SomeTable
             where t.Value1 = someValue
             select new SomeTableDTO()
             {
                  Value1 = t.Value1,
                  Value2 = t.Value2,
                  SomeParent = new SomeParentDTO()
                  {
                      Value3 = t.SomeParent.Value3,
                      Value4 = t.SomeParent.Value4
                  }
              };
```

This works, but the problem is I am repeating the same code over and over again because there are many DTOs that have a SomeParent property.

```
var result = from t in DatabaseContext.SomeOtherTable
             where t.Value5 = someValue
             select new SomeOtherTableDTO()
             {
                  Value5 = t.Value5,
                  Value6 = t.Value6,
                  SomeParent = new SomeParentDTO()
                  {
                      Value3 = t.SomeParent.Value3,
                      Value4 = t.SomeParent.Value4
                  }
              };
```

I'd like to do something like this so the conversion for the SomeParentDTO can be shared:

```
var result = from t in DatabaseContext.SomeTable
             where t.Value1 = someValue
             select new SomeTableDTO()
             {
                  Value1 = t.Value1,
                  Value2 = t.Value2,
                  SomeParent = SomeParentConverter(t.SomeParent)
              };
```

.

```
Func<SomeParent, SomeParentDTO> SomeParentConverter = (parent) =>
{
    return new SomeParentDTO()
    {
        Value3 = parent.Value3,
        Value4 = parent.Value4
    };
};
```

But of course this doesn't work because `Invoke` is not supported in LINQ to Entities.  [This posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621062/select-values-in-anonymous-type-with-func-in-linq-select-statement) seems to be going in the direction I want, but that uses a single `Expression` that is passed to `.Select()`, and that doesn't solve my DRY problem.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). It supports mappings in [IQueryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions).

Part of the sample from the documentation:

```
public List<OrderLineDTO> GetLinesForOrder(int orderId)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Item, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Item.Name);

    using (var context = new orderEntities())
    {
        return context.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.OrderId == orderId)
                    .Project().To<OrderLineDTO>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought AutoMapper just tried to match things up based on similar property names, I didn't know it could influence what fields were ultimately selected in SQL.  I will need to try this.