# linq mysql : select multiple column and send the to view

Tags: mysql, linq, select

I have selected multiple columns from my table, but I don't know how to pass it to my view.

```
 var result = (from f in db.firmware
               where f.firmware_release_type_text != "" 
                     || f.firmware_release_type_text != null 
                     || f.firmware_release_number_int != 0
               select new{
                    f.firmware_release_type_text, 
                    f.firmware_release_number_int
               }).Distinct();
```

The result is f__anonymous2. I want to some how use it in my view. all the forums have just answered how to choose multiple columns, but nobody mentions how to pass them. I think I'm missing something obvious.

I want to be able to use this fields, or even merge them as one string.

I have tried Cast and so many other options which did not work.

When I try to force casting it sting, I get :

```
Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'System.String'
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

At the end I went with:

```
var result = (from f in db.firmware
              where (f.firmware_release_type_text != "") 
                    && (f.firmware_release_type_text != null) 
                    && (f.firmware_release_number_int != 0)
              select  new{
                          f.firmware_release_type_text, 
                          f.firmware_release_number_int
                      }
              ).Distinct();

        List<string> result2 = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            result2.Add(item.firmware_release_type_text 
                        + "-" + item.firmware_release_number_int);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return your data as a string you have to say how it should be formatted. You could for example change this:

```
select new
{
    f.firmware_release_type_text , f.firmware_release_number_int
}
```

To this:

```
select f.firmware_release_type_text + " v" + (int)f.firmware_release_number_int
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I get :

 System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.  @Mark Byers

Comment: Sorry it didn't occur to me  that you were using Entity Framework, but in hindsight it should have.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, and I get this error :

 Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: the first one can be null which is a string.

and I get 
: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

I'm going to o through everything once more, and see if I can do anything about it

Comment: @Athena: I found a useful link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502842/int-to-string-in-entity-framework Answer: SqlFunctions.StringConvert

Comment: @Athena: Is there any good reason why you can't do the conversion to string *after* you've fetched the data from the database?

Comment: I thought may be it's better not to go through the list one more time. Thanks a lot for the help. I went with the conversion after fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to create a model first, second format the data on the server side.