# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.Object)' method,

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am getting `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` error when I am trying to concatenate number with string in LINQ? how to resolve this?

```
     Dim initiativeDataList As IEnumerable(Of InitiativeData) = 
         SGAEntities.Fact_Initiative.Where(Function(factInitiative) factInitiative.Client_Idx = client_Idx).[Select](
             Function(factInitiative) New InitiativeData() With { _
                         .ClientIdx = factInitiative.Client_Idx,
                         .HierarchyIdx = factInitiative.Hierarchy_Idx,
                         .CostCenterIdx = factInitiative.Cost_Center_Idx,
                         .LocationIdx = factInitiative.Location_Idx,
                         .InitiativeIdx = factInitiative.Initiative_Id,
                         ....
                         ....
                        .Location = String.Concat(factInitiative.Location_Idx) + ";" + factInitiative.Dim_Location.Location_Name,
             }).ToList()
```

Comment: I don't think you wanted to include just *one thing* in the Concat, anyway. But perhaps this related question can help you get your number as a string inside your query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502842/int-to-string-in-entity-framework

Comment: use SqlFunctions.StringConvert to convert int to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)factInitiative.Location_Idx) + ";" + factInitiative.Dim_Location.Location_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just concatenate strings with `+`.  If you were using `Concat` for an implicit string conversion, consider using `SqlFunction.StringConvert`