# Error with converting int to string in Linq to entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

I am trying to concatenate some fields in the given code. It works for only the string fields but when i concatenate int field then the error comes.

```
var query = (from u in db.IdFormat
                 select new
                 {
                     IdPre = u.IdPrefix + "" + u.IdDMY + "" + u.IdSeparator + "" + u.Sequence.ToString() 

                 }).FirstOrDefault();



public class IdFormat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String IdPrefix { get; set; }
    public string IdDMY { get; set; }
    public string IdSeparator { get; set; }
    public int IdSequence { get; set; }      
}
```

But getting error message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [int to string in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502842/int-to-string-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities does not support as many conversion of functions to server hosted sql.

ToString (on anything) is one of them.

Here's a post suggesting workarounds:
 http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/08/24/LINQ-to-Entities-what-is-not-supported.aspx

and here is a list of supported functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

Here is a post asking how to convert int to string:
[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 0):

use LintToObject  _db.IdFormat.**AsEnumerable()** :

```
var query = (from u in db.IdFormat.AsEnumerable()
                 select new
                 {
                     IdPre = u.IdPrefix + "" + u.IdDMY + "" + u.IdSeparator + "" + u.Sequence.ToString() 

                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```