# MySql Linq to SQL conver int to string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I have a MySQL and LINQ to SQL task to convert Int value from DB to String, 
toString() is not supported by MySql, and I am getting error about it.

```
var data = (from o in ObjectContext.MyTable.Where(d => d.a == a)
                              select new MyObject
                              {
                                  Id = o.Id,
                                  StringProperty = o.intColumn.ToString()
                              });
```

SqlFunction class is not suported for MySql.

Comment: ToString() (capital T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the results to Enumerable and then query on it:

```
var data = (from o in ObjectContext.MyTable.Where(d => d.a == a)
                              select new MyObject
                              {
                                  Id = o.Id,
                                  StringProperty = o.intColumn.ToString()
                              }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: This will work, but all the data in the table will be enumerated (fetched) here, if I'm not mistaken. May be a bad idea if you have lots of data.

Comment: *At least* do .AsEnumerable() after the Where.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch all the data by adding `AsEnumerable()` to the table, or you could do the fetch first, then the conversion later - if I'm not mistaken, this should produce a slightly lighter SQL call:

```
var tempData = (from o in ObjectContext.Where(d => d.a == a) select o);

var converted = (from o in tempData.AsEnumerable()
                select new MyObject
                          {
                              Id = o.Id,
                              StringProperty = o.intColumn.ToString()
                          });
```

Alternatively, write it all in one go by using the first part as a sub query:

```
var data = from x in 
                  (from o in ObjectContext.Where(d => d.a == a) select o)
                  .AsEnumerable()
           select new MyObject
                           {
                              Id = x.Id,
                              StringProperty = x.intColumn.ToString()
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

[int to string in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502842/int-to-string-in-entity-framework) 
also had supported a great solution you can refer.  By this method you can change you source as the following.

```
var data = (from o in ObjectContext.MyTable.Where(d => d.a == a)
                          select new MyObject
                          {
                              Id = o.Id,
                              StringProperty = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)o.intColumn)
                          });
```