# cast IList<int> to IList<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, controller, converters

code in my EFService:

```
    private IDbSet<Item> _Items;
    private int _SearchTakeCount = 10;
    public IList<string> SearchByArticleCount(int articleCount)
        {
            return _Items.AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Articles.Count().Equals(articleCount))
                .Take(_SearchTakeCount)
                .Select(m => m.Articles.Count().ToString())
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
        }
```

code in my Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult AutoCompleteSearch(string term, KeywordSearchBy searchBy = KeywordSearchBy.Name)
        {
            IList<string> data = new List<string>();
        switch (searchBy)
        {
            case ItemSearchBy.Name:
                data = _ItemService.SearchByName(term);
                break;
            case ItemSearchBy.ArticleCount:
                int articleCount = Convert.ToInt32(term);
                data = _ItemService.SearchByArticleCount(articleCount);
                break;
        }
```

when I run the project the exception is accured.
this exception is:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Just as a side-note - what you are doing is a "conversion", not as "cast". Casting doesn't change the instance of the variable, conversion creates a brand new instance of a new variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `ToString()` call as LINQ to Objects query, after EF part is done:

```
public IList<string> SearchByArticleCount(int articleCount)
{
    return _Items.AsNoTracking().Where(m => m.Articles.Count().Equals(articleCount))
        .Take(_SearchTakeCount)
        .Select(m => m.Articles.Count())
        .Distinct()
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => x.ToString())
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Essentially EF does not know how to convert numeric value to string. The above said solution will work. Also, you can try the solution mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502842/int-to-string-in-entity-framework