# ToString() inside where method

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to to find products in my db using where and contain. When I run this code, it works as intended and it returns the products that Iam searching for:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        var products = from p in _db.Products
        select p;
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString));
        }
       
        return View(products);
    }
```

However I want to see if the user search for Id as well, so I did something like this:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        var products = from p in _db.Products
        select p;
        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString) || 
            p.Id.ToString().Contains(searchString));
        }
       
        return View(products);
    }
```

In my mind, if the user search for id=2 then it should return products that have "2" in its Id, right? But for some reason I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(__searchString_0) ||
> p.Id.ToString().Contains(__searchString_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a
> form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.
> g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, ref <>c__DisplayClass8_0 )

I have tried to do this is JavaScrip as well, and it works as intended there;

```
this.filteredProducts = this.products.filter(s => {
                return s.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchedWord.toLowerCase()) || 
                s.id.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.searchedWord.toLowerCase());
                });
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20839

Comment: Just a note: in my mind, when a user searches for an ID, they are looking for something specific and not wanting a range of results. In such a case, Contains() would not be appropriate as it could return multiple results.

Comment: The message says that the LINQ expression could not be translated to SQL, so you will have to execute it on the client. Also, you probably got the Contains parameters reversed

Comment: This illuminates one of the biggest issues with using an ORM. Either execute a raw query that you write yourself and does the job, or select all records and filter them in-memory.

Comment: Depending on the DB and its settings, the search is probably already case independent, so you can probably remove `ToLower()`. So `Id` is a number (probably an `Int32`?), so why even bother searching it, if your `searchString` isn't a number? You could use `if (int.TryParse(searchString, out int searchNumber)) { /* search in Id, too */ }`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, yea my bad, edited now. ToString() was what I meant.

Comment: @Corak: probably because OP wants a substring search to support finding products with ID={123, 123456} if you search with `"12"`

Comment: One of the comments in the github link by haim770 makes it seem like this is a bug introduced in Framework ver. 6.44. Your code SHOULD work, the commenter in that link indicated they rolled back to ver. 6.20.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - right... missed that. -- does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4540953/1336590

Comment: @TerryTyson how would you have solve it then? Lets say I only want 1 result and the search bar is the same for both name and id.

Comment: @zlatan114r Just don't use Contains(). s.id.ToString().toLowerCase() = this.searchedWord.toLowerCase());

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have come with a solution. It might not be the best solution, but atleast it work as I want it to. I used this:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var products = from p in _db.Products
    select p;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString) || 
        (""+p.Id).Contains(searchString));
    }
   
    return View(products);
}
```

Comment: why does (""+p.Id) work?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your query like this:

```cs
p.Id.ToString().Contains(searchString)
```

You can write it using the `Like` function in `EF.Functions` like this:

```cs
EF.Functions.Like(p.Id.ToString(), "%" + searchString + "%"));
```

Now your `int` Id will be cast to string on the db side and you can for example search for `2` in `520` like you wanted.

#### Notes

1. If you're using SQL Server you don't have to call `ToLower()` when using `Contains` because the default collation for SQL Server is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` which is case-insensitive.
   See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity).
2. Starting EF Core 2.0 you can use the `DbFunctions` class which has alot of powerful functions. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.1).

### Update

This is a small working example:

Action:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromQuery] string query)
{
    var data = await applicationDbContext
        .DbModels
        .Where(d => EF.Functions.Like(d.Id.ToString(), "%" + query + "%")).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Model:

```cs
public class DbModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Postman output:

[image]

The problem is definitely from your end.

Comment: I tried this and I got the same error.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                products = products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString) || EF.Functions.Like(p.Id.ToString(),"%" + searchString + "%"));
            }

Comment: @zlatan114r This is probably because of the `ToLower` call.Try to call your query without the `ToLower`.

Comment: I tried without the ToLower, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @zlatan114r Weird! I can guarantee that it's working and i've used it multiple times. What's your EF Core version? Try updating your ef core packages.

Comment: Any idea how I can check my EF Core version?

Comment: @zlatan114r See the installed nuget packages in your solution via `Dependencies` > `Packages`.

Comment: > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore   3.1.1   3.1.1
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore  3.1.1  3.1.1
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI    3.1.1    3.1.1
   > Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core         2.2.5       2.2.5
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design       3.1.4       3.1.4
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite    3.1.4       3.1.4
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.SqlServer   3.1.3       3.1.3
   > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools    3.1.1       3.1.1

Comment: @zlatan114r Try updating EF Core to the latest version.

Comment: I updated to the latest version. I still have the same problem. I see in your update that you use ToListAsync().

Comment: @zlatan114r `ToListAsync()` is to materialize the query in order to return it.